# Is this a network issue of installing nixos

Tags: installation, nixos

After taking those prerequisite steps like prepairing NixOS ISO liveCD,partitioning my SSD ,mounting those partitions and editting the configuration.nix file appropriatedly,then i ran the command `sudo nixos-install --show-trace`in Cli under /mnt directory,when the building went to *perl-5.36.0.tar.gz.drv*,there was always an error:**unable to download ...** and another error:**filesystem error,can't rename...** at last .
So what's really going on there?i tried many times and the curl to the cpan source was good .My Nixos installer's version is 22.11